# sed append multiple lines with special characters through bash file

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

Ive been trying to figure this out for a awhile now but need to phone the experts.

```
sed '/#algoscreens/ a\
'${coinname}'="screen -dmS '${coinname}' bash $STRATUM_DIR/run.sh 
'${coinsymbol}.${coinalgo.conf}'"\
'${coinname}'stop='screen -X -S '${coinname}' quit'' stratum
```

which needs to read

```
a5a="screen -dmS a5a bash $STRATUM_DIR/run.sh a5a"
a5astop='screen -X -S a5a quit'
```

then I have

```
 sed '/#algocommands/ a\startstop_'${coinname}'() {\
 cmd=$1\
 case $cmd in\
    stop) '${coinname}'stop ;;\
    start) '${coinname}' ;;\
    restart)\
        '${coinname}'stop\
        sleep 1\
        '${coinname}'\
        ;;\
esac\
}\' stratum
```

which needs to read

```
startstop_a5a() {
cmd=$1
case $cmd in
    stop) $a5astop ;;
    start) $a5a ;;
    restart)
        $a5astop
        sleep 1
        $a5a
        ;;
esac
}
```

then finally

```
sed '/#shift/ a\
'${coinname}') startstop_'${coinname}' $cmd ;;' stratum
```

which needs to read

```
a5a) startstop_a5a $cmd ;;
```

I keep getting a  bad substitution error.

Comment: `bad substitution` sounds more like a shell error than an error from sed itself - did you perhaps mean `${coinalgo}.conf` rather than `${coinalgo.conf}` ?